# Why does Java Date have "GB" times as an hour off?

Tags: java

We're having an issue with some Java data functions where Java seems to think that London is in DST, only I'm not sure why, they aren't. The following is a code snippet that shows the problem.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    TimeZone t = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GB");
    TimeZone.setDefault(t);
    Date d = new Date(38182478);
    System.out.println(d.toString());
}
```

With an output of

```
Thu Jan 01 11:36:22 GMT 1970
```

Where I would have expected

```
 Thu Jan 01 10:36:22 GMT 1970
```

Why is this happening?